# Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on null values.

Tags: sql, sql-server, wpf

Hi I have nulls in a table that I will use to populate a combo box. I am not sure how to do this. When I run the below code I get the error: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on null values.

```
private void code()
    {
        sc.Close();

        try
        {
            sc.Open();
            string Query = "SELECT * from CodeTable";
            SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, sc);
            SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                String code = dr.GetString(1);


                if (!cbDevices.Items.Contains(code))

                    {
                        cbDevices.Items.Add(code);
                    }


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe show more debug info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is just to filter them out in your SQL:

```
"SELECT * from CodeTable WHERE code IS NOT NULL"
```

I'm assuming that the field name is `code` based on your sample, but you can adjust appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out null using [IsDbNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) .

```
if (!dr.IsDbNull(1))
{
  String code = dr.GetString(1);

  if cbDevices.Items.Contains(code))
  {
     cbDevices.Items.Add(code);
  }
 }
```